# How do I match raster values with point values

Tags: raster, r, sf

I have an sf point file and a raster, each in the same crs.
I want a df with in rows, only the raster cells that match (geographically) with a point from the sf file, where one column should display the sf point value and another column should display the raster value.
How do I go about?

Comment: Can you read the raster in using the `terra` package? Look at the `extract` function which I think is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the stars package.

```
library(stars)
library(sf)
my_raster <- read_stars("./path/to/my/raster.tif")
my_points_sf <- read.csv("./path/to/my/points.csv") %>% st_as_sf(.,
                                             coords = c("x", "y"),
                                             crs = 28992)
st_crs(my_points_sf) <- st_crs(my_raster)
pts <- my_raster %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_intersection(my_points_sf)
pts
```